# WPDB inserts 0 in one specific field

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, insert

I'm trying to learn how to use WPDB so I just wrote a simple code to insert data in a 5-row database table.
All fields are inserted without a problem, except for one text field (*course_desc*), which for some reason only gets "0" as a value. When I edit the value via PHP My Admin, it works fine. I can't get my head around it.

[Here is my table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBwFe.png) and here's the code:

```
global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix.'courses';
        $data = array(
            'course_title' => 'This is a title',
            'course_desc' => 'This is a description',
            'course_time' => 28,
            'course_link' => 'https://whatever.org'
        );
        $format = array('%s', '%d');
        $wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is un-tested but I think you need to add two more items to your `$format` array to account for all the columns you are inserting for.  Below I added to more `%s` formats.  Hope this helps!

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'courses';
$data = array(
  'course_title' => 'This is a title',
  'course_desc' => 'This is a description',
  'course_time' => 28,
  'course_link' => 'https://whatever.org'
);
$format = array('%s', '%s', '%d', '%s');
$wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);
```

Comment: ... I feel really dumb. That obviously was it, thank you very much!